# Check self visibility from inside user control

Tags: vb6, user-controls, visibility

How do I self-test the visibility of a user control?

There is no `UserControl.visible` or similar property.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the userControl to `VBControlExtender`

```
Dim oVBControlExtender As VBControlExtender
Set oVBControlExtender = UserControl.Extender
If oVBControlExtender.Visible = True Then
'Code Here
EndIf
```

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff and it isn't "casting" at all anyway.  All you are doing is getting a strongly-typed reference to the Extender property of the UserControl.  There is generally no reason to explicitly drop the reference either.  Quite the cargo-cult fest going on here.

Comment: @xvan: What Bob77 means is that this is a very convoluted way to use `Extender.Visible` per se. Both the simple way and your convoluted way lack error handling, for when the container's site visibility property is named `IsVisible` for instance.